# Ambigious reference to member tableView.reloadData() when I change the function to class func, to use the function in another swift file

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to call function of one swift file in another. I do so by adding class in front of the function. But when I change the func to class func, I receive error on the tableView.reloadData() which did not have error before. The error is 'ambigious reference to tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection). I would like to remove the tableView error since I want the function to be called in another swift file also. This is the code I have been trying with:

```
class func filteredContentForSearchText(searchText:String, scope: String = "All"){
    var filtered: [String] = []

    let UniName: [String] = ["ATLANTA MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", "AUSTIN SURGICAL HOSPITAL", "BAPTIST MEDICAL CENTER", "BOWIE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL",
                             "COLLEGE STATION MEDICAL CENTER", "COVENANT MEDICAL CENTER","HUNT REGIONAL COMMUNITY HOSPITAL","METHODIST HOSPITAL","PARKVIEW HOSPITAL"]


filtered = UniName.filter{car in
    print(filtered)
return car.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)
}
tableView.reloadData() }
```

How could I reload the tableView so that I can get the new search results of the map kit at the same time I need to use this function in another swift file.

Comment: It shouldn't be a class function.  Your class doesn't have a table view, instances of your class do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably want to make this a delegate method and not a class function.

Define the delegate with a protocol:

```
protocol HospitalSearchDelegate {
    func filteredContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String)
}
```

Then in your swift file that needs to call it create a property:

```
var delegate: HospitalSearchDelegate?
```

Assign the property then call it as:

```
delegate?.filteredContentForSearchText("Search", scope: "All")
```